# How to append var to a URL in ajax post

Tags: ajax, function, jquery, append

The loop gives me the last li using the var westring. Is there a way to attach or append it to the post URL?

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var westring = '0';

    $('#infinite_topic_scroll').scrollLoad({ 
    url : '/challenges_side.php?f=hh&start_res='+westring+'&v=y', 
    getData : function() {  },
    start : function() { $('<div class="loading"><img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif"/></div>').appendTo(this); },
    ScrollAfterHeight : 95,
    onload : function( data ) {
    $(this).append( data );
    $('.loading').remove();     
    },
    continueWhile : function( resp ) {

    var westring = ($(this).children('li').length);

    // alert(westring);

    if( $(this).children('li').length >= 100 ) { return false; }
    return true;
        }
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find much on the plugin you're using specifically, but I think what you're looking for is in...

```
getData : function() {  }
```

Try something like this...

```
[...]
url : '/challenges_side.php', 
getData : function() 
{  
    return {
        "f" : "hh",
        "v" : "y",
        "start_res" : $(this /* or element selector */).children('li').length.toString()
    };
},
[...]
```

I could be wrong, but it's worth a shot

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the var inside the continueWhile function. You already placed the var in the above scope.  Also, I would cast it to a string.It should just be

```
westring = $(this).children('li').length.toString()
```

Comment: if I take it out of the continueWhile function where would it count the total? The whole problem is I need to send the total to get the results

Comment: Just remove the word "var" inside the function, because you already declared "westring" above outside of this function.